# Python Cassandra Table models for object mapping filter "LIKE"

Tags: python, filter, cassandra, objectmapper

-> Table Document

```
id int (Primary_key)
title text (Partition_key)
name text
```

-> Custom Index

```
title
```

-> How to find the title with python mapper object using LIKE?

-> thanks you

Comment: Custom index using what ?

Comment: CREATE CUSTOM INDEX search_title ON project.document ( title ) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = { 
'analyzed' : 'true', 
'analyzer_class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 
'case_sensitive' : 'false', 
'mode' : 'CONTAINS' 
};